# We are planning to integrate shopify and wordpress

Tags: node.js, wordpress, shopify

We are planning to integrate shopify and wordpress.
It will be reverse proxied to WordPress, but the URL will change after that.

Each URL is as follows :

1)Shoify Site: 
https://reverse-nodejs.myshopify.com/

2)wordpress site: 
https://reverse-nodejs.myshopify.com/apps/journal

3)(original) wordpress site: 
https://www.plany.work/apps/journal

The settings are as follows :
[shopify app proxy setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lL3I.png)

The proxy code is as follows :

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
   //modify the url in any way you want
   var newurl = 'https://www.plany.work';
   request(newurl).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Please tell me if there is a solution for this problem.